NTFS compression & ghost disk space
I have a source NTFS compressed folder
S:\Source\
size 16 GB
size on disk 8 GB 

And I have a target drive T:, NTFS just formatted, 4096 block size, with compression enabled and 20 GB free.
Now I run RoboCopy to copy folder tree :
from S:\Source\
to   T:\Target\

At a certain point RoboCopy fails with ... not enough space on the disk
If I check the Target folder, its size is much less than 16 GB and less than 8 GB on disk. It "looks" compressed but only a subset of the source files has been copied to target.
The target drive T, has no free space. All 20 GB seems used.
Obviously, some of the missing target disk space, i call it the ghost space, is used by the background compression process.
But, even if I wait one or more days, that ghost space is never released. The 20 GB target disk will remain 100% full, 0% free space, with less then 10 GB used for user files n disk.
If I run the ChkDsk command on Target drive T:
ChkDsk T: /V /scan /perf

some times the ghost space is released, some times it isn't released because of locked files.
If I run the "brute" ChkDsk command on Target drive T:
ChkDsk T: /V /F /X /scan /perf

all the file handles are closed by force, the disk is unmounted, checked, fixed and mounted again. And finally the ghost space has been released.
But on this way, with all the file handles dropped, I cannot be sure of the disk files integrity !!! Their handle buffer in memory has been cleared by force without saving on disk.
I tried to copy, from source to target, one by one per time, each source subfolders
S:\Source\Sub01\
S:\Source\Sub02\
S:\Source\Sub03\
...

And I've realized that :

compression ratio from source to target is almost the same
for every 1 GB of uncompressed source files, it is occupying on target 1 GB of target files plus about additional 1 GB of ghost disk space.

It seems that the copy process will copy the files on target first in uncompressed mode and than compress them in background.
So, the questions :

How can I analyze/show where/what the ghost space on target disk is?
How can I release that ghost free space without brute force?
How can I check/monitor the background compression system process and push it up?

I would avoid third party tools, remaining in the Windows utils domain.

Something doesn’t seem right. There is no compression that exists that would allow a 50% compression. So your data is not actually 16GB and it’s not actually compressed to 8GB

Please avoid using multiple explanation marks (!), one is enough, but only when grammatically correct. Using it for every sentence isn’t grammatically correct.
